# Is there any way to send SMTP messages with the password obfuscated?

Tags: c#, smtp

I am building a program that sends something to my e-mail.

The problem is that if I have a look at my program through Reflector, I can see my password. I tried using SecureString, but it also shows my password.

Is there any way to completely obfuscate my password from start to end?

Comment: Uhm, not very clear, you don't need to use your email account and password to send an email to your email account...

Comment: @steve oops i meant the other account which is sending email to my account

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot store secrets in a .net application. However, you can store the password in a store (registry or file) encrypted using the account of the application user - however that user will get to see the password; but other users cannot. In your circumstance, since you dont want to hide your password from yourself, that would seem to do the trick ?